# Text page over footer

Tags: html, css, footer

[image: Text page over footer]

I need to put the text page over the footer as illustrated in the picture attached. It is important that the length of the page is set to auto according to the text in page.

Comment: 1. What all code you have already tried ? What is your exact problem area? Its very important that you mention what things you have tried along with the html + css code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative margin to the top of the footer and set a z-index of 2 for the text.

```
.footer{ margin-top: -100px;}
.text-page {position: relative; z-index: 2;}
```